# Get the windows account which runs the query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, permissions

I'm using sql server 2008 r2.

I logged in to ssms which in turn connects to a remote sql server machine.

im writing a query which writes a file.

I need to know - which windows permissions I should grant to `c:\myfolder`

is there any `select query` which can provide me the windows account who is actually finally writes  the file ?

[image]

Comment: FYI http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/18756

Comment: @RemusRusanu it is from a paper not a board. :-) but thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends, and I'm afraid Martin give you only part of the answer. The credential used to access the file is different whether you logged in with SQL login or a Windows login.

For SQL logins (ie. user and password based connection string) the credential used is either the SQL server process account of the [login proxy credential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161950.aspx) account, if one is set up:

> The information stored in a credential enables a user who has
>   connected to SQL Server by way of SQL Server Authentication to access
>   resources outside the server instance. When the external resource is
>   Windows, the user is authenticated as the Windows user specified in
>   the credential.

For Windows logins (ie. Integrated Security or SSPI connection string) the engine will always impersonate the caller before accessing outside resources. Which implies that the access to the shared folder will occur under the impersonated context of the original Windows login. Which in turns implies 'double-hop' delegation will occur and the authentication with the shared file will be subject to the domain policies on constraining delegation. And all domains that give 1 cent on security will have constrained delegation restriction in place and will require you to set up the SQL Server service account to be enabled for constrained delegation.

Comment: I need to tell the IT manager : "please grant access to ____" . Is three any `select account` which shows me the value of  `"______"` ?

Comment: The closest thing is Martin's suggestion to run `whoami`. But I suggest a different approach. Ask not what the account is -  ask how can the account be set. Create a domain account for this purpose, grant access to this account, the create a credential in SQL for it and have the SQL login [use this credential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190703.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

It will be the SQL Server service account.

If `xp_cmdshell` is enabled (or you have permissions to temporarily enable it) you can use

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'whoami'
```

Comment: will the 'whoami' result and the service account will always  be the same ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Yes AFAIK

Comment: This is not true for Windows logins, the call will be impersonated and subject to delegation. Is also incorrect for SQL logins that have set up a Windows credential.